# Style of Cycling Caps

Tags: helmets, sun-protection

I am looking at Bicycle Caps. I would like recommendations as to the style that would be most comfortable.

My head is shaved and my bike helmet is not soft enough.

The benefits of a shaved head are quite numerous :-)

Here is a (cropped) picture of my helmet.

[image]

Comment: Is your helmet comfortable as it is currently?  No cap/casquette is going to improve the fit of an uncomfortable helmet.

Comment: I am cleaning up - all the points about the light's mounting are detracting from and not helping this question.    If I move your comment its not censorship, it is keeping this question on track.   A separate question about "how to secure accessories to helmet" would be better.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145622/discussion-on-question-by-fixit7-style-of-cycling-caps); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @Criggie Your comments have not been helpful. You have been critical and not helpful. I kindly suggest that if you can not be helpful, then do not post.

Comment: @fixit7 I have tried to focus this post back onto your original question about caps. and moved the safety comments off into their own separate chat.   All the remaining comments and all the answers relate to this question as asked.  I can't see how that would be interpreted as critical/unhelpful.

Comment: I've deleted the comments about sunburn. The OP never mentioned sunburn as a problem and indicated that it isn't a problem in the previously deleted comments. Those comments can still be viewed [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145622/discussion-on-question-by-fixit7-style-of-cycling-caps).

Answer (score 8):

If you need a peak/brim/visor, then a traditional cycling cap is really the best option.  They generally have one panel of cloth that covers the scalp backward to the elastic at the rear.   The parts above your ears are their own semicircular panel.   These are also known as casquettes (from french) and not "caskets" which are to be avoided even though they sound similar.

Baseball caps are to be avoided - they tend to use 6 triangular panels sewn to a single point on the top, which is closed by a snap or permanent dome/rivet.  These are uncomfortable and dangerous in a collision, and can interfere with MIPS sublayers functioning.

Finally, if you just want padding then look for a skull cap or a buff.  Skull caps are close-fitting and may have a brow line that follows a normal hairline while dipping down to cover the ears.

A buff is essentially a shapeless tube of light/thin material with some elastic properties.  Both should sit under a helmet without adding pressure spots.

Do be aware that your helmet will need to adjust outward to allow for the extra material between you and the sub-frame.  Sweating will increase because ventilation decreases.

A final option is to stop shaving and allow some natural hair to grow back - this may not be a feasible solution for all readers.

---

The rear/sides of your neck are also exposed - some people like to use a "legionnaire" style of sun-shade around the back.  This one is a cycling cap not a baseball cap.

[image]

Comment: One detail: cycling caps come in two varieties: made from cotton and from polyester (or similar synthetic fibers). The latter is much better. The former will wick sweat but remain wet. It will irritate your forehead regardless of the presence of hair elsewhere on your head.

Comment: "cycling caps come in two varieties: made from cotton and from polyester (or similar synthetic fibers)" Don't forget wool!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Excellent point - that's worth making as a separate answer focusing just on materials.   Pure wool vs wool combo, and how wool can still be an excellent choice in the heat of summer under the right conditions.

Comment: A buff used as a cap may need to be smoothed out; they seem to want to bunch up. But they work nicely. Some may be too thin to offer much sun protection (like the cheap black one I bought to double as a sleep mask)

Comment: I actually prefer cotton because it stays wet. It's much better for cooling than letting the sweat that doesn't evaporate right away to drip. The second benefit is that it doesn't get stinky like synthetic fibers.

Answer (score 7):

For sun protection of your head under your helmet during the summer, many brands make exactly the product you are looking for: You should search for terms like *Cycling Skull Cap* or *Bike Summer Skullcap* or *Cycling Summer Beanie*.

[image]

Make sure to explicitly check the sun protection qualities of the material used (usually included in the description).

I cannot post links to specific products because we don't generally answer shopping questions.

Comment: These can also be found at generic sporting goods stores where they are sold to be worn under any sporting helmet -- American football and baseball, and probably cricket and equestrian sports as well.

Answer (score 6):

For riders with very short hair a triangle folded bandana tied at the back of the head works well to prevent sunburn through the helmet vents and serves the other purposes of keeping a layer of sweat next to the skin for cooling and reduces the amount of sweat that falls into your eyes.

A bandana is tiny and can be stashed in a jersey pocket in case of an unexpected sunny day.

Cotton/poly-cotton isn’t an ideal sun-screen but works well for this particular use. Probably [darker colors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/whats-the-upf-of-a-t-shirt-or-jeans) are better.

Comment: Your responses shows that you carefully read my post.

Comment: I also most often wear triangular headscarf. Also often when walking in the mountains, without any helmet. Always thin synthetic ones, cotton just get soaked with sweat. I never had a problem with lighter - yellow ones even witout any helmet. Actually, when cycling I wear it mostly to get the sweat away from my face.

Comment: @fixit7 your earlier version mentioned cooling and 20+ deg temperatures. This is how I protect myself from heat and sun and it may been a good solution for you.

Comment: @Warren Burton I am NOT hair challenged. I made the decision to shave my head.

Comment: @fixit7 did you shave them off entirely, as in a buzz cut? Why does this make a difference with regard to lack of hair?

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather stay away from the entire light mounting system safety discussion, but one solution may indeed be to replace your helmet. You can fix the comfort problem without having to get an additional cycling cap. Your existing helmet looks quite old, and the padding is likely wearing out. The foam gets saturated with dried sweat and starts losing its springiness, and the fabrics can start getting scratchy. Also, the shape of a helmet arguably has the biggest impact on how comfortable it is. Finding one that better matches your head shape means there's fewer pressure points and you're less reliant on the padding to provide you with comfort.

If possible, going up in price range can help as well. Here's a photo of the inside of my mid-range helmet (Giro Source MIPS). There's visibly more and thicker padding than yours, and the fabric has smaller pores, which will feel nicer against bare skin.

[image]

Additionally, if you insist on mounting stuff to the front of your helmet, getting a helmet which reaches further down the back of your head can help stabilize the whole assembly. It's difficult to stabilize an asymmetrically-loaded hemispherical helmet without cranking up the retention strap tension or the chin strap tension, neither of which are going to help your comfort issues.

Answer (score 2):

Sunburn is best dealt with using a very high protection sun block. If you head is getting burnt though the helmet vents, you should be applying it to you face and neck anyway.

Marino wool skull cap is my personal choice for an under helmet covering. These come in very thin single panel and will provide similar feel as hair between helmet and skin.  There are 'high tech' synthetics that work as well as Wool. Avoid anything with thick seams, and anything too thick (unless you need if for cold).

Comment: Have you ever worn a helmet with pads that are saturated with old sunscreen?

Comment: @ojs: They get this slimy feeling where you can literally scrape of grime with your finger nails. It’s only a cosmetic problem.

Comment: @Michael exactly. Different people may have different opinions, but I do not like having that stuff on my skin.

Comment: @Michaeal - Where I live, we have very high UV levels and the highest Melanoma rates in the world. Use of sunscreen (and accepting its down sides) when doing outdoor activities is considered essential by most people.  I have noticed in other parts of the world sunscreen is almost considered a cosmetic.

Comment: My dermatologist recommends SPF clothing or any clothing over sunscreen.

Comment: Current recommendations are _not_ to apply sunscreen above the eyes.

Comment: @DavidW would you have a source for that? My quick search was inconclusive, or rather pointed the other way.

Comment: It was an ophthalmologist (not a dermatologist) who had seen a number of cyclists, specifically, with eye irritation from sunscreen migrating into their eyes.  Cycling helmets are pretty much the worst thing to put over sunscreen, because you'll still sweat some and any movement of the helmet pads over the skin will scrub sunscreen off the skin into the sweat.  When that comes down into your eyes...  (It was on a TV program a year or so ago; I've totally lost the reference.  My searches now are swamped by dermatologists' "put sunscreen on everything!!1!")